# AdminLTE3 - how to close Control Sidebar instead of toggle

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, adminlte

I am using [AdminLTE3](https://adminlte.io/themes/v3/index.html) as an admin theme in my project.

What I am trying to do is to find a **JS code which can close right sidebar**, called "Control Sidebar Plugin"

I know I can use this code to toggle (open/close) sidebar, but I need to close it instead of toggle.

```
<a href="#" data-widget="control-sidebar" id="my-toggle-button">Toggle Control Sidebar</a>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#my-toggle-button").ControlSidebar('toggle');
```

BTW: Manual of AdminLTE3 did not mention how to close it directly: https://adminlte.io/docs/3.0/javascript/control-sidebar.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this

```
> html
<aside class="control-sidebar control-sidebar-light">
</aside>

> js
$('.control-sidebar').ControlSidebar('collapse');
$('.control-sidebar').ControlSidebar('show');
// or
$('.control-sidebar').ControlSidebar('toggle');
```

Comment: Could you add some more explanation?